# symfony2 Doctrine delete an array of objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to delete all the records from database matching a particular user_id in Symfony2.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user_service = $em->getRepository('ProjectTestBundle:UserService')
->findByUser($this->getUser()->getId());
```

This might return a few matching objects, so when I run:

```
$em->remove($user_service);
$em->flush();
```

an error occurs:

```
EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.
```

How do I remove all records (objects) matching a particular condition? 
Btw, when I run an equivalent sql statement in mysql, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 30):

Why don't you just loop through the objects array?

```
$user_services = $em->getRepository('ProjectTestBundle:UserService')
->findByUser($this->getUser()->getId());

foreach ($user_services as $user_service) {
    $em->remove($user_service);
}

$em->flush();
```

Comment: no problem, sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees... happens :P

Comment: Indeed :)) I tried while/for loops before; forgot about foreach for a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i was thinking there is a solution in Doctrine style. :)

Comment: As @zennin, I was expecting for a Doctrine native solution. Althought I didn't want to use the loop, I think it will do the trick ;D

Comment: Don't loop when working with databases. This will send a single statement for every element to the database. It's ok with 3, but not ok with 1000.

Answer (score 6):

You can also make use of doctrine query builder `delete` method.

```
public function deleteAllByUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('related_entity')
        ->delete()
        ->andWhere('related_entity.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: Probably the fastest when working with many objects in comparison to the other solutions.
I do wonder why an array as a parameter in the "$em->remove()/persist()" methods is not accepted. But there must be a good reason for it!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use something like this:

```
$user_services = $em->getRepository('ProjectTestBundle:UserService')->findByUser($this->getUser()->getId());
array_walk($user_services, array($this, 'deleteEntity'), $em);
$em->flush();
```

Then add this method in your controller:

```
protected function deleteEntity($entity, $key, $em)
{
    $em->remove(entity);
}
```

Or simply use:

```
$user_services = $em->getRepository('ProjectTestBundle:UserService')->findByUser($this->getUser()->getId());
$this->deleteEntities($em, $user_services);
$em->flush();

...

protected function deleteEntities($em, $entities)
{
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $em->remove($entity);
    }
}
```

Note that when using `Propel` and the `PropelBundle`, the `PropelObjectCollection` implements a `delete()` function so you don't have to do this loop by hand.

Comment: For the first method, couldn't you just do `array_walk($user_services, array($em, 'remove'));` ?

Comment: Yes indeed, but in the `deleteEntities` method, so you don't have to rewrite this code each time.

Answer (score -1):

If you return one object, you just need to write:

```
 ->findOneByUser,
```

You won't need a foreach loop. If your return is an array, then you need to do `->findByUser` and write a for loop:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity)
{
  //do something
}
```